# Is there a simple embeddable web server available for .net that supports PHP?

Tags: php, .net

I want to add a simple web server to my .net windows service project that supports PHP.  I have scoured the internet for something that I can embed into my project without a lot of success.  The closest thing I found was Mongoose which used to have support for c#, but as of Sept. 2010 that has been discontinued due to problems with Vista/7.  Does anyone know of any .Net libraries or open source solutions that would allow me to embed a web server into my project that supports PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing I found was this: http://webserver.codeplex.com/

Someone made a modification to it to support PHP and it is working great

http://webserver.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=236909

Answer (score 0):

Why not write your own web server in C# and call PHP from within your code?

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/article.php/c4603

Comment: of course this is a possibility, but I was hoping to not reinvent the wheel if it have already be done